# Equal margin between inline elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m using the bootstrap grid system with full-width and I want to have a section, where I have four img-elements with equal margin and the margin should be responsive. The section is in the center of the page.

I could say for every img-element margin-right: 20px or something like this, but can I get this also responsive?

```
<div class="row" id="content_services">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                <section id="services_section">
                    <img src="pictures/test.jpg" alt="Test" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="pictures/test.jpg" alt="Test" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="pictures/test.jpg" alt="Test" class="img-responsive">
                    <img src="pictures/test.jpg" alt="Test" class="img-responsive">
                </section>
            </div>
        </div><!-- END ROW CONTENT_SERVICES -->
```

The stylesheet:

```
#services_section{
}
#services_section img{
    height: 275px;
    width: 275px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its only ever going to be 4 elements - use a nested column structure. Each image will display across the page in a single row across the screen on medium and large viewports, will display in pairs on small viewports and will stack vertically on small viewports. You will still need to style the images to display in the center of each (either with a text-center class on the parent div as I have done or via css on each img). If you need to alter the number of images - remember that the magic number is 12 - each column can be divided into 12 columns so you can alter the sizings for different numbers of image elements.

Also just note that a section semantically requires a heading (h1 - h6 - which defines its title ) within its structure to be valid html5. Hope this helps, Gavgrif

```
<div class="row" id="content_services">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 text-center">
                <section id="services_section">
                  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="pictures/test.jpg" alt="Test" class="img-responsive">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="pictures/test.jpg" alt="Test" class="img-responsive">
                 </div>                 
<div class="col-md-3  col-sm-6">
                    <img src="pictures/test.jpg" alt="Test" class="img-responsive">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="pictures/test.jpg" alt="Test" class="img-responsive">
                 </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div><!-- END ROW CONTENT_SERVICES -->
```